# Move view itself to animation's end position

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, view, position

I'm having a real serious problem.
I want to implement UI where some view is moving on the screen and the user can touch it.
I know that regular API-1 Animation framework move just the graphics of the view, and API-11 Animator framework move the view itself, but the problem is that it support only API-11+ which is very high.

I thought that instead of putting click listener on the view itself - I will identify which item was clicked by getting its position.
So this is what I will do:
* User touch the screen.
* Stop all the animations.
* Get all the animated views to the position where the animation was ended. (This is were I need your help).
* Iterate over the views and find out if the click was in the area of one of them.

But I can't find a way to move the view to the animation's end position.

If someone knows a way, I will be very thankful!

Thanks in advance,
Elad

Comment: You can use Jake Wharton's NineOldAndroid library, which backports the Animator framework back to - I believe - even API level 1.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried Jake Wharton's great library, but unfortunately the views are also not touchable on pre-11. It moves just the graphics, as the old Animation framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I can't find a way to move the view to the animation's end position.

Modify its `LayoutParams` to move it to the end position. Use `getLayoutParams()` on the `View`, cast it to the appropriate type based on its container, modify the `LayoutParams` object, then call `setLayoutParams()` on the `View` to commit the changes.

Comment: Actually, I can't find the actual position, moving the view itself is not a problem. I mean, when user touch the screen I don't know where is the view in the current moment. This is what I try to find.

Comment: While this works, it will force a layout pass which depending on your view hierarchy's complexity can be too slow to do per-frame and still hit 60 (or sometimes even 30) frames per second on some devices. It can be a reasonable and quickly implemented fallback for older platform versions (while using the new animation system instead when available), but if you're looking for smoothness on those older versions it'll take a bit more work.

Comment: @adamp: Is there a better solution, pre-API Level 11, that we're missing?

Comment: @Elad92: Oh. Um. I don't know that this is possible, short of you taking educated guesses (e.g., track the elapsed time and run the calculations yourself to determine where the view is), or grabbing the `TranslateAnimation` source code, putting it in your project (under your own package), modifying it to expose this sort of data, and using that rather than the built-in one.

Comment: @CommonsWare: A custom parent view could do it. Calling `layout(left, top, right, bottom)` on the child you want to move around is nearly free as long as the actual width and height of the child aren't changing. (If the width and height are the same, the child view's frame is moved but its `onLayout` method is skipped.) This is in essence how ListViews (and other adapter-based views) "scroll." As long as the custom parent's `onLayout` maintains the correct position for the child with an animation in progress in case a layout pass happens for another reason, you're good to go.

Comment: @CommonsWare: if you're looking for a simplified example of this sort of use of the `layout` method you might look at the `updateTextPositions` method of `PagerTitleStrip.java` from the support lib. It uses this same idea to shuffle 3 TextViews around as the user scrolls or the parent pager animates.

Comment: @adamp, can you please explain the way you've suggested in more details? I would like to understand it so I can implement it.

Comment: @Elad92: Have a look at the support library code I mentioned above for an example. This way would involve implementing a custom ViewGroup. Depending on how much and how often this view moves around, the framerate increase on older platform versions may not be worth the increased complexity in your code over CommonsWare's suggestion of simply altering and re-setting the LayoutParams. It may be worth investigating if you're not satisfied with the framerate of the simpler solution.

Comment: @adamp, I thought you were talking about finding the position of animation, sorry. 
@CommonsWare, Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to dig in the `TranslateAnimation` code and will report if I find something that can help me.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks you very much. Someone from my team did it like you suggested: currChangeX = elapsedTime*totalDistance/totalTime; He was able to get it by overriding getTransofrmation() on the Animation class. Thanks you very much, I will mark your question as the correct one.