# Android - LayoutTransition hides views inside the animated view before closing it

Tags: android, android-animation, layouttransition

I have a `LinearLayout` that contains several views - when I add or remove it from my view I used the default `LayoutTransition`.

I'm adding the view to my AppbarLayout - and I added the animations programmatically  by setting a new LayoutAnimation on the appbar before adding the view and setting it to null after the view is added - I don't do it using the tag in the xml due to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191170

The problem is that when i remove it from the view the default animation is done in two parts

1. all the views inside immediately disappear
2. the closing of the view is animated from bottom to top

Which change is needed to the `LayoutTransition` in order to have only the **2nd** animation where the view is closed from bottom to top?

Answer (score 0):

[CommonsWare answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132431/4497835)

> Modify its LayoutParams to move it to the end position. Use
>   getLayoutParams() on the View, cast it to the appropriate type based
>   on its container, modify the LayoutParams object, then call
>   setLayoutParams() on the View to commit the changes.

Comment: How is this related to the question I asked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
LayoutTransition transition = container.getLayoutTransition();
transition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.APPEARING);
transition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING);
```

Comment: Didn't work - I tried with changing the visibility of the container and with adding and removing it from the root view - but the disable you suggested didn't solve my issue

Comment: @NoaDrach strangely enough, because I tested it myself and it works as you want; by the way, you've just added android:animateLayoutChanges="true" attribute to LinearLayout attributes or you've done something else?

Comment: I didn't add it to the xml because of this issue - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=191170 - so I'm setting a new LayoutTransition on the root view (AppbarLayout in my case)  before i call appbar.addView - and then I set the TransitionLayout on the appbar as null

Comment: @NoaDrach now I get it, hope someone will help you